# Switching .NET 1.1 webservice to WCF safely?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

Is it safe to switch a .NET 1.1 webservice to a WCF service, knowing that not all clients use .NET to access the service? So they use the SOAP/XML method. Can we switch to WCF without the clients having to change code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  While I haven't done it with a 1.1 web service, I was able to refactor a .NET 2.0 webservice into a WCF service, then just expose it with basicHttpBinding.  The client didn't even know the difference.

I dug through some of my saved links when I was working on it, and [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924045258/http://geekswithblogs.net/marcel/archive/2007/09/27/115662.aspx) and a [good msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/config-wcf-service-with-aspnet-web-service) were what got me started.  Really simple and to the point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You could make SOAP/XML or even JSON coexist for your WCF services, this way you still support the existing protocols.

Check the first result from google by seaching **"WCF SOAP JSON POX"**
I am quite sure that is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Is it .NET 1.1 that's providing the data or that's consuming it?

.NET 1.1 web services didn't handle nullable types, so die horribly if they try to consume web services provided by .NET 2.0 that include nullable ints, for example.

[I'm not sure whether this would apply to WCF, but it would be worth checking.]